# What is the (file) format of iOS/iPhone apps?

Tags: ios, file-format

I know that Android apps are packaged as *.apk files, but I have no idea in which way an iOS/iPhone app is stored?

Assuming that iOS apps need to be developed and up- and downloaded to the apple App store I assume that the app is stored as a file. Which format does this file have?

Comment: sort of, I searched via startpage.com (that takes google results) and "file format ios app" did not yield that much, sorry.

Comment: all my bad, sorry, went also on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ios where no info was found, before asking the question. I am so sorry the question was concrete answerable and not hard enough to merit. please downvote

Answer (score 30):

> An .ipa file is an iOS application archive file which stores an iOS
>   app. Each .ipa file includes a binary for the ARM architecture and can
>   only be installed on an iOS-device.

[.ipa (file extension)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension))

Answer (score 8):

`.ipa` file extension is used for Apple iOS application file and
`.ipsw` file extension is used for iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch iOS software firmware update file.

Other file extensions or file formats developed for use with Apple iOS 
`.aee , .applesyncinfocpbitmap , .cpbitmapdfu , .dfuimg3 , .img3ios , .iosipb , .ipbipcc , .ipccithmb  , .ithmbk48  , .k48m4r  , .m4rmapsdata  , .mapsdatambdb  , .mbdbmbdx  , .mbdxmdinfo  , .mdinfometriclog  , .metriclogmobileconfig  , .mobileconfign81  , .n81n88  , .n88n90  , .n90n90ap  , .n90apn92  , .n92provisionprofile  , .provisionprofilesinf  , .sinfsmil  , .smilsupp  , .supp_ipod_control  , ._ipod_control`

Comment: can we use ipa on iPad ?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, an ".ipa" is a zip file. If you rename the suffix you can easily unzip it and go into the "Payload" folder and look at the app... which is just a package.

Answer (score 1):

ipa file witch is actually a normal zip file

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) What are you adding here on top of the other answers?